# Completely positive, unital maps acting on unitary operators [solved]

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, complete-positivity

Call a completely positive, *irreducible*, unital map $E$ on the operators on a finite-dimensional Hilbert-space *primitive* if there is only a single eigenvalue with modulus 1 (all others have modulus <1) and furthermore the corresponding eigenspace is one-dimensional. This eigenvalue is then necessarily equal to 1 and the eigenspace spanned by the identity operator. Irreducible in this case means that the (unique) fixed point $\rho$ of the Hilbert-Schmidt dual $E^*$ is strictly positive.
(This last clarification was added after I thought to have found an example to my question below, which, however, was not irreducible. See below.)

Now consider such a map $E$ and suppose that there exists a unitary and hermitian operator $U$ (hence $U^2=1$) that is itself mapped to a unitary (and hermitian) operator by $E$.
If it is mapped to a multiple of itself, then $U=\pm 1$ by primitivity, so let's assume that it is mapped to a unitary that is not proportional to the identity.
My basic question is whether this is possible (i.e., an example of such a map $E$ would make me happy, as would a proof that $U$ would have to be $\pm 1$).

Note that by equality in Kadison-Schwarz, we have that $E[UX]=E[U]E[X]$ and $E[XU]=E[X]E[U]$ for all $X$. Since $U^2=1$, we further have $U=P-Q$, with $P$ and $Q$ orthogonal projectors such that $1=P+Q$. It's not very difficult to deduce that $E[P]^2=E[P]$ using equality in the Kadison-Schwarz inequality and similarly for $Q$. It follows that also $E[PX]=E[P]E[X]$ and similarly for $Q$ (and the opposite ordering). If one could show $E[P]\leq P$, then any $PYP$ would be mapped to $PE[PYP]P$. Since $E$ is primitive and hence irreducible, this would imply $P\in\{1,0\}$ and therefore $U=\pm 1$.

It is easy to construct examples of non-primitive, unital CP-maps where $E[P]\leq P$ is violated and yet $E[P]^2=E[P]$ for a non-trivial projector $P$. But for primitive ones I somehow did not succeed yet, although I would not be too surprised if there is a simple counter-example.

Any insight would be very much appreciated!
I asked this question previously on stack-exchange, but maybe I have more luck here. Maybe unsurprisingly, the problem appeared in an argument in quantum information theory, but has now become a problem on its own :-)

**Update 2:** The following provides an example that is not irreducible, but fulfills all other requirements.
Consider $\mathbb{C}^3$ as Hilbert-space with the Euclidean inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$.
Pick an orthonormal basis $e_i$ and choose $E$ as
$ E[A] = \begin{pmatrix} 
\langle e_1,A e_1\rangle & 0&0\\
0& \langle e_1,A e_1 \rangle &0\\
0& 0& \frac{1}{2}(\langle e_2,A e_2\rangle + \langle e_3,A e_3\rangle)
\end{pmatrix}$

This is clearly unital and completely positive. A small calculation shows 1 is the unique eigenvalue with modulus 1 and the eigenspace is one-dimensional. However, it maps
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 &-1 & 0\\
0 & 0 &-1
\end{pmatrix} 
\mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that the map is not irreducible, since the projector onto the space spanned by $e_1$ is an eigenvector of $E^*$.

**Update 3**: The above example can in fact be generalized to the irreducible case. To do this, follow the above map $E$ with conjugation by a unitary $V$ that maps the basis $\{e_i\}$ to a basis that is [mutually unbiased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_unbiased_bases) with respect to the $\{e_i\}$:
$$\tilde E[A]=V E[A]V^*.$$ 
Then the map becomes irreducible, since the only fixed point of $\tilde E^*$ (up to normalization) is $\mathrm{diag}(2/3,1/6,1/6)$ in the basis $\{e_i\}$, but $\tilde E$ maps
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 &-1 & 0\\
0 & 0 &-1
\end{pmatrix} 
\mapsto 
V \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} V^*, $$
showing that indeed it is possible to find an example with $U\neq \pm 1$.

Comment: What is a primitive map?

Comment: An irreducible positive map with trivial peripheral spectrum, i.e., where 1 is the unique, non-degenerate eigenvalue with modulus 1. I realize this might not be standard terminology and have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: When you say non-degenerate eigenvalue, do you mean "the eigenspace is one-dimensional"? (Not complaining about your terminology, just wanted to make sure)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: sorry to keep nitpicking, but in the new version, do you mean the following: (a) 1 is an eigenvalue, and all other eigenvalues have modulus less than 1, and the eigenspace of the eigenvalue 1 is dimensional; or (b) there is only one eigenvalue with the properties "has modulus 1 and has 1-dimensional eigenspace", and that eigenvalue is 1 ?

Comment: I meant option (a). I have rephrased the question and hope that it is clear now.

Comment: A simple example where $E[P] \not\leq P$ is the following: Let $E: \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2} \to \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ be given by $E[A] = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} \operatorname{tr}(A) & 0 \\ 0 & \operatorname{tr}(A) \end{pmatrix}$. For $P = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ we then have $E[P] \not\le P$. Unfortunately, this does not answer your original question, though.

Comment: While this example doesn't answer my problem, it lead me to finding a simple example that does answer my problem, so thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @HenrikWilming: That's funny: for the last 30 minutes or so I was quite convinced that such an example could not exist and that I only had to find a proof for this... :-) Anyway, you're welcome! (And I really like your counterexample!)

Comment: @JochenGlueck: And in fact you might still be right! I just realized that my example is not irreducible, as I was asking for (see updated question).

Comment: @HenrikWilming: Oops... I think I was buying to easily your former claim that primitivity plus the existence of a "strictly positive" fixed point implies irreducibility. This is, for instance, indeed true for non-negative contractive matrices that operate on $\mathbb{C}^n$ endowed with the $\ell^1$-norm; but it is not true on $C^*$-algebras (as your example shows).

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Yes, I think I was fooling myself similarly. But the newly added example solves this loophole.